# GCM Diagnostics shows messages only for production package name

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

How can I have GCM diagnostic information for a develop version of an app?

The GCM Diagnostics page, under https://play.google.com/apps/publish/, correctly shows message information when I send messages to the main package, but not when .debug is added as a suffix. I can successfully send messages to either app using the same API key and the appropriate Registration ID. For reference here is my test message sending code, straight from the quickstart example.

```
// Create connection to send GCM Message request.
URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);

// Send GCM message content.
OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(jGcmData.toString().getBytes());
```

Interestingly both of the Registration IDs end up being mapped together and the dashboard returns only the one message sent to the the app with the production package name.

Comment: Do you have the same Project ID for both versions of your app?

Comment: There is only one project. The

Comment: In that case you'd have the same SenderID which seems like the cause.